# Securing 2 applications deployed to the same WebLogic server by blocking public access

Tags: java, security, weblogic12c

I have 2 applications deployed to the same WebLogic server. They are talking to each other over REST calls.
I know I can secure both application and make those calls secure this way but my question is rather about preventing those REST calls to be accessible from outside. Is it possible to exclude them from public access at all? 
I would like the apps to talk to each other over the REST but reject any external REST call. One of them has public access but it is Struts application and has no REST public interface.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to answer this question by myself in case someone may need it.
This is purely theoretical conclusion and I never tried that in real life but I believe it can work this way and then the communication between 2 application doesn't have to be additionally secured.

It is possible to configure WebLogic this way. WebLogic instance sports a kind of internal virtualization and can consist of (and usually do) set of virtual hosts and managed servers, which main purpose is horizontal scaling when necessary. Each managed server is a separate container and can contain deployed application, bunch of such servers can form a cluster but don't have to, they can act as standalone servers too. Everything together is controlled by module called Admin Server.

In above scenario 2 managed servers act as a separate instances, they contain each application deployed to it. Managed Server A serves application A on port A while Managed  Server B serves application B on port B.
Now managed servers are configured the way that only Server A has a public access while  Server B is not accessible from outside. This way application A is public and anyone can access it while application B is not public and is accessible only internally.
Since both managed servers work on the same machine they can still talk to each other internally regardless of port configuration of the machine.